# Is there any good reason not to use unicode as opposed to string?

Tags: python, unicode

Many problems I've ran into in Python have been related to not having something in Unicode. Is there any good reason to not use Unicode by default? I understand needing to translate something in ASCII, but it seems to be the exception and not the rule.

I know Python 3 uses Unicode for all strings. Should this encourage me as a developer to `unicode()` all my strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, I'm going to say "no" there's not a good reason to use `string` over `unicode`.  Remember, as well, that you don't have to call `unicode()` to create a unicode string, you can do so by prefixing the string with a lowercase u like `u"this is a unicode string"`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just start doing that from now on.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x:

- A `str` object is basically just a sequence of *bytes*.
- A `unicode` object is a sequence of *characters*.

Knowing this, it should be easy to choose the correct type:

- If you want a *string of characters* use `unicode`.
- If you want an *string encoded as bytes* use `str` (in many other languages you'd use `byte[]` here).

In Python 3.x the type `str` is a string of characters, just as you would expect. You can use [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#bytes) if you want a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Python 2.6+ also has bytearrays, if you want your bytes in something a little more mutable.